# If $\gamma : J \to M$ is a curve on manifold $M$ of dim $n$, then $\gamma$ is an immersion iff $\gamma'(t) \neq 0 \forall t \in J$.

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry

> Show that if $\gamma : J \to M$ is a smooth curve in a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, then $\gamma$ is a smooth immersion if and only if $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in J$.

*Proof:* $(\implies)$ We'll prove the forward direction via the contrapositive. Suppose that $\gamma'(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0 \in J$. Then by definition of $\gamma'$ we have $$\gamma'(t_0) = d\gamma_{t_o}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t_o}\right) = 0 \in T_{\gamma(t_o)}M.$$ Since  $d\gamma_{t_o}$ is a linear map from $T_{t_0} \mathbb{R}$ to $T_{\gamma(t_0)} M$ we have $d\gamma_{t_o}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t_o}\right) = 0 = d\gamma_{t_0}(0_{T_{t_0}\mathbb{R}})$ thus $d\gamma_{t_0}$ is not injective and so $\gamma$ is not a smooth immersion.

$(\impliedby)$ If $\gamma'(t_0) \neq 0$ for all $t_0 \in J$ then $d\gamma_{t_o}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t_o}\right) \neq 0$ for all $t_0 \in J$ hence $\operatorname{Im}(d\gamma_{t_0})$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$ which has dimension $n$ and since $$\operatorname{rank} d\gamma_{\gamma(t_0)} = \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{Im}(d\gamma_{t_0})) = 1 = \operatorname{dim}(T_{t_0}\mathbb{R})$$ we have $d_{\gamma_{t_0}}$ to be injective and so $\gamma$ is a smooth immersion. $\square$

---

Is my proof above correct? If not where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why the contrapositive? The direct proof is immediate.

Comment: @TedShifrin I initially didn't see how to do a direct proof for the forward direction, but I can see it now. A direct proof would be the following: If $\gamma$ is a smooth immersion then $\operatorname{rank} d\gamma_{t_0} = 1$ for all $t_0 \in J$ and this implies that $\gamma'(t_0) \neq 0$ for all $t_0 \in J$ because if $\gamma'(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0 \in J$ then $\operatorname{Im}(d\gamma_{t_0}) = \{0\}$ because $d\gamma_{t_0}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t_0}\right) = 0$, but then $\operatorname{rank}d\gamma_{t_0} = 0$ a contradiction.

Comment: LOL, a proof by contradiction is not direct!

Comment: @TedShifrin I know :p  But I was just trying to motivate that part, like if you leave everything out after (and including) the word because then that would be a direct proof I think?

Comment: @Perturbative, I think your solution is correct. I just think you could have written it more directly, like this: "$\forall t_0\in I$, we have $T_{t_0}I=\text{span}\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t_0}\right)$, so $\gamma$ is an immersion at $t_0$ $\Leftrightarrow \ker(d\gamma_{ t_0})=0$ $\Leftrightarrow \text{rank}(d\gamma_{t_0})=1$ $\Leftrightarrow d\gamma_{t_0}\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t_0}\right)\neq 0$ $\Leftrightarrow \gamma'(t_0)\neq 0$".

Comment: $J$ is an interval in $\mathbb R$?